# Optimization of the log-absolute: reformulating to DCP-compliant on Julia

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am trying to reformulate this optimization problem in order to get a DCP-complaint expression on `Julia` (I am using the `Conjex.jl` package)

$$
\text{Minimize}\;\;\; \mid\log(x)\mid
$$

The code

```
p = Variable()
f = abs(log(p))
```

Prompts to a warning

> WARNING: Expression not DCP compliant. Trying to solve non-DCP compliant problems can lead to unexpected behavior.

I am beginner regarding convex optimization. But, [as far as](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html#functions) I read

> CVX-family does not consider a function to be convex or concave if it is so only over a portion of its domain, even if the argument is constrained to lie in one of these portions

Hence, the problem seems to be that the function $\mid x\mid$ is nonincreasing for $x < 0$ (even though it is outside the domain, it is analyzed), and nondecreasing for $x>0$. I suppose that the [composite property](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html#compositions) fails because of it.

How to reformulate it in order to get DCP-compliant expresison?

PS: solutions using other scientific programming languages (Matlab, R, Python...) is welcome too.

Comment: The problem is that $|\log(x)|$ is only convex for $0<x<1$, then has a spike at $x=1$ and then is concave. So if you assume $0<x<1$ then you can minimize $-\log(x)$, in the other part $x>1$ nothing can be done. Unless you can somehow reformulate the whole problem, or just use a general nonconvex solver.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek yeah, that is my question, can I state that this problem is equivalent to?
$$
\text{Minimize}\;\;\; \mid x - 1 \mid
$$

Comment: If this is the whole objective then it should be equivalent